# Index a SciPy sparse matrix with an array of booleans

Tags: python, indexing, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

NumPy arrays can be indexed with an array of booleans to select the rows corresponding to `True` entries:

```
>>> X = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
>>> rows = np.array([True,False,True])
>>> X[rows]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> X[np.logical_not(rows)]
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

But this seems not possible with SciPy sparse matrices; the indices are taken as numeric ones, so `False` select row 0 and `True` selects row 1. How can I get the NumPy-like behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) (or `ndarray.nonzero`) on your boolean array to get corresponding numerical indices, then use these to access the sparse matrix.  Since "fancy indexing" on sparse matrices is quite limited compared to dense `ndarray`s, you need to unpack the rows tuple returned by `nonzero` and specify that you want to retrieve all columns using the `:` slice:

```
>>> rows.nonzero()
(array([0, 2]),)
>>> indices = rows.nonzero()[0]
>>> indices
array([0, 2])
>>> sparse[indices, :]
<2x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 6 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Comment: If you change `rows.nonzero()` to `rows.nonzero()[0]` in the index into `X`, I'll accept this answer. It seems to work even without the `:` suggested on [scipy-user](http://old.nabble.com/numpy.compress-and-sparse-matrices--td23943683.html).

Comment: Indexing also works for tuples, at least for "normal" ndarrays.  For multidimensional indexing, you cannot use `nonzero()[0]`.

Comment: Not with SciPy sparse matrices: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

Comment: OK, I played a bit with sparse matrices and updated the answer.  Seems that you actually do need the `:` slice since otherwise, for `rows = (0, 2)`, you won't get a submatrix, but only the single element at `(0, 2)`.

Comment: There's `numpy.flatnonzero(bools)` as an alternative to `bools.nonzero()[0]` as well. Is there a reason a sparse matrix like csr that's designed for being row-sliced can't handle the boolean indexing of rows?

Comment: Using `numpy.where()` instead of `numpy.nonzero()` is a little bit more intuitive.